# How to replace every 3rd and 4th integer with an asterisk

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I want to print a star (*) in place of every 3rd and 4th value of a range of numbers.  So for input 20 I would want to print:
1 2 * * 5 6 * * 9 10 * * 13 14 * *
... etc.

The code below is my attempt thus far.

```
public static void main(String arg[]) { 
  int i;
  for(i = 1; i <= 20; i++){ 
    if(i % 0 == 0 || i % 4 != 0) { 
      System.out.println(i);
    } else {
      System.out.println("*");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for what you've tried so far?

Comment: class Dcoder{
 public static void main(String arg[]){
  int i;
  for(i=1;i<=20;i++){
   if(i%0==0|| i%4!=0)
    {
   System.out.println(i);
     }
  else 
  System.out.println("*");
 
        }
    }
}

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74443/fizzbuzz-problem-solution

Comment: this is not what i want

Comment: i want a for loop where every 3rd and 4th value is print as * eg: 1 2 * * 5 6 * * 9 10 * * 13 14 * *

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do it.  I'm sure there are more elegant solutions.

```
int counter = 0;
int i;
for(i = 1; i <= 20; i++){ 
  if(counter == 4) {
    counter = 0;
  }
  if(counter < 2) {
    System.out.println(i);
  }
  if(counter > 1 && counter < 4) {
    System.out.println("*");
  }
  counter++;
}
```

Comment: If this solved your problem please mark it as correct so we can get it closed.

Comment: is there any other method using %

Comment: I can't think of any method off the top of my head.  For example, you would have to use something like `i % 3 == 0` to catch the first location to print an asterisk.. but that would also catch 6 (which shouldn't be printed as an asterisk).  That is why I am doubtful.

Comment: {int i;

for(i = 1; i <= 100; i++){ 

   if(i%4==3 || i%4==0)
    { System.out.println("*");
     }
    else{
     System.out.println (i);
     }
      }
   }
}

Comment: This is i got now